# Remove "No break space"

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have these **`<U+00A0>`** at certain positions in my text. I already tried to use remove it like this:

```
Text<- gsub("<U+00A0>"," ",Text)
```

But this only seems to work if it is in front of the words. It still remains in the text like this:

```
"In<U+00A0>conclusion"
```

I hope you can understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: try adding `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to escape the `'+'` sign with `\\`

```
Text<- gsub(pattern = "<U\\+00A0>"," ",Text)


> Text <- "In<U+00A0>conclusion"
> gsub(pattern = "<U\\+00A0>"," ",Text)
[1] "In conclusion"
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct way is to use `\uXXXX` syntax e.g. `Text <- gsub("\u00A0", " ", Text)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not as good as wolf_wue's answer. But if all the "`<U+00A0>`" are at the last digits of your string, you can use "substr" function to only retain the rest of your string.

```
# head(WEA$Text)
# [1] "0.0<U+00A0>" "0.0<U+00A0>" "0.0<U+00A0>" "0.0<U+00A0>" "0.0<U+00A0>" 

Text =substr(Text, 1, nchar(WEA$Prcp)-8)
head(Text)
[1] "0.0" "0.0" "0.0" "0.0" "0.0" "0.0"
```

Comment: Similar logic can be applied when <U+00A0> appears at all leading digits of a string variable.